# SQL not returning rows present in table correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have an issue with a table in a database. There are three columns as follows:

```
Name (VARCHAR(25))
QText (TEXT)
AText (TEXT)
```

My query is run through PDO as:

```
SELECT `AText` FROM `Exam_QA_Data` WHERE `Name` = '$name' AND `QText` = '$question'
```

After processing it looks like this and obviously the length of the `$question` variable will change:

```
SELECT `AText` FROM `Exam_QA_Data` WHERE `Name` = 'ExamServerTestExam' AND `QText` = 'This is the first question'
```

From what I can see depending on the length of the string in place of `$question`, sometimes it will return a row, other times it returns nothing.

If the string is short (27 chars) then it returns the `'AText'` content for that row, though if the string is long (106 chars) nothing if `$question` is a long string.  I checked the entry in the database and the entire string is present, so the row is there exactly as it is being searched for.

I have also tried using:

```
SELECT `AText` FROM `Exam_QA_Data` WHERE `Name` = '$name' AND `QText` LIKE '%$question%'
```

Can't understand if this is a database issue or not and if so why?  It appears to be a problem with the length of the input string.

Thank you very much.

Comment: for qtext have you tried not equals (=) but like? does change the behaviour?

Comment: tried this......AND `QText` LIKE '%$question%'..........and I get the same result

Comment: and if you use the query on php my admin or similar it works without error?

Comment: no it gives nothing....same thing, with a short string it works in both PDO and phpmyadmin, but a long string fails for both

Comment: i suppose that the problem is the qtext string. Try to search that sting with phpmyadmin search feature, see if you can find some of that and which query it does use

Comment: looks like `mysql` not `sql-server` so i've removed that tag

Comment: Is this user input? There may be hidden characters that you are not seeing, such as `/n` or `/r`, maybe try `LIKE '%$question%'` instead.

Comment: Side note: you are not using PDO correctly. You should provide input data as *parameters* rather the injecting them into the raw SQL code.

Comment: they are put in as parameters, its within a function.....the only hardcoded part is the table name, phpmyadmin search feature didnt find it either, and I dont think it is hidden characters because this EXACT same function works with a shorter string that is input with the exact same method (from a HTML <option> tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some tests, I discovered that the search doesn't like a string that is over 80 characters long.  In order to do this but still get the same result I input the string with a wildcard as shown in the following codeblock:

```
function grab_ans_given_ques($conn, $question, $examName){

    // Split the string here into two parts and join with a wildcard (%)
    $ques = substr($question, 0, 20)."%".substr($question, -20, strlen($question));
    $sql  = $conn->prepare("SELECT `AText` FROM `Exam_QA_Data` WHERE `Name` = '$examName' AND `QText` LIKE '%$ques%'");
    $sql->execute();
```

Thank you all who gave some advice or tried to help with this!